# HttpClient 4.3.5 ConnectionRequestTimeOut vs ConnectTimeout for HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout in 4.0.1

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to upgrade our HttpClient Dependency from 4.0.1 to 4.3.5. And was confused on setting the connection timeout in the new lib. For the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 300);
```

It will be replaced with the code below:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(300).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
```

However, I am not sure if I should use **setConnectTimeout** or **setConnectionRequestTimeout** since I am not familiar with HttpClient. It seems to me I should use **setConnectionTimeout** based on the java doc in the source code. Can somebody please confirm? Thanks in advance.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.3.3/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.java

```
/**
 * Returns the timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection
 * from the connection manager. A timeout value of zero is interpreted
 * as an infinite timeout.
 * <p/>
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).
 * <p/>
 * Default: <code>-1</code>
 */
public int getConnectionRequestTimeout() {
    return connectionRequestTimeout;
}

/**
 * Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * <p/>
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).
 * <p/>
 * Default: <code>-1</code>
 */
public int getConnectTimeout() {
    return connectTimeout;
}
```

Comment: connection TO and request TO are very diff things. single conn set up may be used by multiple requests. each req has its own timeout value . The connection TO may only refer to the action that sets up the connection

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857327/should-i-still-set-connectionrequesttimeout-on-apache-httpclient-if-i-dont-use) which is about ConnectionRequestTimeout setting

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In version 4.3 of Apache Http Client the configuration was refactored (again).
the new way as the following code:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig =RequestConfig.custom()
.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
.setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionRequestTimeout)
.setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout).build();
```

`connectTimeout` is the timeout until a connection with the server is established. `connectionRequestTimeout` is used when requesting a connection from the connection manager.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Helped me resolve a critical issue. :)

Comment: @Meysam is it mandatory to provide `setConnectionRequestTimeout` any idea what is worst thing could happen?

Answer (score 28):

Difference between the three timeouts in Apache HttpClient :

`connectTimeout` max time to establish a connection with remote host/server.

`connectionRequestTimeout` time to wait for getting a connection from the connection manager/pool. (HttpClient maintains a connection pool to manage the connections. Similar to database connection pool)

`socketTimeout` max time gap between two consecutive data packets while transferring data from server to client.