# Should I still set ConnectionRequestTimeout on Apache HttpClient if I don't use a custom connection manager?

Tags: java, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using [Apache RequestConfig](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html) to configure some timeouts on my `HttpClient`.

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
        .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout) // Can I leave this out..
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        //.setConnectionManager(connectionManager) // ..if I don't use this
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
        .build();
```

Does it make any sense to call `setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)` even I don't have a custom Connection Manager / Pool set up?

As far as I understand, `setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)` is used to set the time to wait for a connection from the connection manager/pool.

Note that I am not setting a Connection Manager on the `httpClient` (see commented line).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`connectionRequestTimeout` happens when you have a pool of connections and they are all busy, not allowing the connection manager to give you a connection to make the request.

So, The answer to your question of:

> Does it make any sense to call setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
>   even I don't have a custom Connection Manager / Pool set up?

is YES.

This is because the [default implementation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) has an internal connection pool.
So, yes it makes sense to specify a connection request timeout. Actually it is a good, safe practice.

Answer (score 13):

Isuru's answer is mostly correct. The default connection manager is a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.
However, by default it will only have one connection in it's pool.
If you are using your `HttpClient` synchronously from the same thread you should never encounter a situation where the `ConnectionRequestTimeout` will take effect.
If you are using the `HttpClient` from multiple threads then you might want to set it, but you would probably also want to increase the pool size, among other things.
For single-threaded httpclient use it is safe to leave it out.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration on Isuru's answer. I'll give the bounty to him since he answered first.