# Apache HTTP Client connectTimeout vs. connectionRequestTimeout

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, connection-timeout

Apache's org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig has both a connectTimeout and a connectionRequestTimeout.

The documentation states that:

***connectTimeout*** - is the timeout until a connection with the server is established
***connectionRequestTimeout*** - is used when requesting a connection from the connection manager

I understand what connectTimeout is and why someone would use it, but I do not understand why someone would set a connectionRequestTimeout. What is an example use case of that?

Comment: give it a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857327/should-i-still-set-connectionrequesttimeout-on-apache-httpclient-if-i-dont-use/37996423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connectionRequestTimeout would happen when you have a connection pool and they are all busy. Depending the application, you are interested in timeout, for example, if you are asking for real time data.